# Disable PHPMailer Redirection

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a page containing a mail form.

```
 <section class="contato" id="inicio-form">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="heading-form" tabindex="-1">Descubra o que a Softcom pode fazer pelo seu negócio</h2>
            <form action="app/mail.php" method="POST" class="js-form" _lpchecked="1">
            <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control form-control-sm required" id="colFormLabelSm" placeholder="Nome" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-sm required" id="colFormLabel" placeholder="E-mail">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <input type="text" name="telefone" class="form-control form-control-sm mask-phone required" id="colFormLabelLg" placeholder="Telefone">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <input type="text" name="cidade" class="form-control form-control-sm required" id="colFormLabelLg" placeholder="Cidade">
            </div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark js-submit" data-text="Solicite uma ativação">Solicite uma ativação</button>

            <div class="msg">
            <p class="msg-error" style="display: none;">Preencha todos os campos corretamente.</p>
            <p class="msg-success" style="display: none;">Mensagem enviada com sucesso!</p>
            </div>

        </form>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And this PHPMailer script:

```
    <?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$nome = utf8_decode($_POST['nome']);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$celular = trim($_POST['telefone'], '_');
$cidade = utf8_decode($_POST['cidade']);

  $content = '
    <h1>Contato Landing Page - Meu Carrinho</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Nome</b></td>
        <td>' . $nome . '</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>E-mail</b></td>
        <td>' . $email . '</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Telefone</b></td>
        <td>' . $celular . '</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Cidade</b></td>
        <td>' . $cidade . '</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  ';

 $mail = new PHPMailer;

  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->Host = 'xxx';
  $mail->Username = 'xxx';
  $mail->Password = 'xxx';
  $mail->Port = xxx;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'xxx';

  $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->Subject =  "xxx";
  $mail->From = 'xxx';
  $mail->FromName = 'xxx';
  $mail->Body = $content;

  $mail->addAddress('xxx@xxx.xx');
  $mail->addAddress('xxx@xxx.xx');

  if(!$mail->send()) {

    $retorno = array(
      'success' => false,
      'message' => 'Não foi possível enviar email.',
    );
  } else {

    if($mail->send()){
      $retorno = array(
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Email enviado com sucesso.',
      );
    }

  }

die(json_encode($retorno));
```

Sending emails is working normally, but the script is redirecting me to a mail.php link with an echo message ({"success":true,"message":"Email enviado com sucesso."}).

How can I disable it and stay at the same page or how can I display this message on the same page?

Thanks!

Comment: Use Ajax to POST your Form Elements to the Desired Page. Then, Return the response Json Object back. Depending on the response, you can show different Messages Like Error, Success etc...

Comment: Have you tried something to prevent the redirect? have you looked in the manual of phpmailer to see if there is an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are passing a json objct as a parameter in die function. This parameter represents the message to printed while exiting from script. Just remove the parameter from die function.

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of asking the wrong question here. PHPMailer has absolutely nothing to do with redirects. that's entirely up to the scripts that you call PHPMailer from, which *you* write.

Your PHP script is being called from JS, which is expecting a valid JSON response, but you're not giving it one. Do this:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($retorno);
```

I'd also recommend that you return a proper HTTP error code - don't return a `200 OK` response when there is an error - return a `400 Bad request` or similar, rather than relying on the `success` property within your JSON. If you don't do this, you may find your browser caches things it should not.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove the code:

```
if($mail->send()){
$retorno = array(
    'success' => true,
    'message' => 'Email enviado com sucesso.',
  );
}
```

Instead of that code place the link where you want to redirect actually.
To redirect, you can use the `header()` function.

For Example:

```
if($mail->send()){
  header("Location: Your_Preferable_PAGE.php");
}
```

At last, also remove `die()` function:

```
die(json_encode($retorno));
```